# What can mess up the order of the tab completion

Tags: auto-completion, cd-command

I am experiencing a difference of behavior between my previous OS (Ubuntu Xenial) and my current one (Ubuntu Bionic).

The short story is this:

When using tab completion with `cd`, the order of the tab completion has changed.

To demonstrate the problem, imagine I have this directory structure (all dirs):

```
/vagrant/hello
/vagrant/hello/web
/vagrant/hello/web/hello.com
```

And I have `CDPATH=.:/vagrant:/vagrant/hello/web`

In the past, `cd hel<TAB>` showed `hello` first, and `hello.com` second:

```
$ cd hel<TAB>
hello/  hello.com/
```

But now, it shows it in reverse order, which is undesirable:

```
$ cd hel<TAB>
hello.com/  hello/
```

Nothing that is under my control has changed between the two versions.

---

The longer story (just for reference, I believe it should not matter):

A) I am a "heavy user" of `CDPATH` - this order change is completely messing up my rhythm.

B) In reality, I am using this `.inputrc` file, to actually do `menu-complete` on tab (the output above is from Shift+Tab, which is the normal `complete`).

```
TAB: menu-complete
"\e[Z": complete
```

C) I have tried reproducing this in a clean (Docker) environment, but I am unable to reproduce the "bad" behavior.

D) I have tried some variations of `menu-complete-backwards` and the likes, but the results are not better.

E) I have tried endless variations of `CDPATH` values, including changing the order and adding `:.` at the end.

F) When doing `cd something<TAB>`, it even seems that the completion will favor directories that are NOT in the current directory, before choosing the ones that are in the current directory - even when `CDPATH` starts with a dot - `.:/other/paths`

I don't know how else to debug this problem, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the locale? in particular, the order seems to depend on `LC_COLLATE`

Comment: `LANGUAGE` is empty, but everything else when running `locale` shows `C.UTF-8` and `locale -a` shows `en_US.utf8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion order appears to depend on the current locale - in particular `LC_COLLATE`

Ex.

```
$ LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
$
$ cd helloTABTAB
hello.com/  hello/      

$ LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
$ 
$ cd helloTABTAB
hello/      hello.com/
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. Not sure if I should just set `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` in my `~/.bashrc` or use a more formal way to set the locale, but I guess I can look it up.

Comment: @DannyB tbh I'm not sure the "right" way to set locales...

Comment: Thats ok, thanks. I guess [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale) is my next stop.

Comment: And the last piece of the puzzle is : `sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8` - thanks a lot, really appreciate it.